# How to create an alias for 2 commands in ConEmu?

Tags: cmder

I have two alias in user-aliases.cmd:

```
title=cmd /c RenameTab "$*" 
ap5pro=ssh  170.63.170.72
```

When calling the first:

```
$ title "sometitle"
```

It works; the tab title changes to "sometitle"

AND when I call the second:

```
$ ap5pro
```

I got the ssh asking me for password, so everything is working.

How can I combine the above two comnands into one in user-aliases.cmd?

Update :

I did these :

```
ap5pro=RenameTab ap5pro $t ssh  170.63.170.72
```

and

```
ap5pro=RenameTab ap5pro & ssh  170.63.170.72
```

but only ssh is executed, never RenameTab.

Comment: What is the problem? Use `&`

Comment: loook at my update, it does not work with & or with $t.

Comment: when I did yours alias ap5pro2=cmd /c "ap5pro=RenameTab ap5pro & ssh 170.63.170.72"   I got    & was unexpected at this time

Comment: Sort of. Play with quotes if it's not working. `alias ap5pro="cmd /c "RenameTab ap5pro & ssh 170.63.170.72""`

Answer (score 1):

alias ap5pro2=cmd /c RenameTab ap5pro $t ssh 170.63.170.72

Comment: Can you explain or expand on this?

Comment: Two years too late - but $T (or $t) is a command terminator in an alias which is the equivalent of hitting enter.  So the above solution just executes the two commands one after the other.